# Python - Move Turtle To Mouse On Click

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'd like to create a program where a turtle object moves to where a user clicks their mouse. I've been experimenting for a while, but I can't seem to get this to work.

```
from turtle import *
from time import sleep
turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
while True:
    screen.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the while loop at all:

```
from turtle import *
from time import sleep
turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)
turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok, I just ran that, and it seems that the program gives the user almost an instant to click. Is it possible to write the program so that it constantly checks where the user clicked? Thank you.

Comment: @Stickman803 Yeah, sorry about that. I fixed it. See my edit.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that I can move another turtle during this time? I tried to put a while loop after your code, but it does nothing until I close the turtle window.

Comment: For future reference, my new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134712